# Swift - How can I convert UNIX time to weekday with an option to offset?

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to make a function that takes in a unix time, timezone, and integer. With the hopes of returning the correct Weekday (Monday, etc.).

```
func unixTimeToWeekday(unixTime: Double, timeZone: String, offset: Int) -> String {
    if(timeZone == "" || unixTime == 0.0) {
        return ""
    } else {
        let time = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: unixTime)
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: timeZone)
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: NSLocale.system.identifier)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: time)
    }
}
```

I am having trouble implementing the offset part. I hope to use it like this...

If today is Monday than

```
unixTimeToWeekday(unixTime: currentUnixTime, timezone: "America/New_York", offset: 1)
```

should return "Tuesday"

and

```
unixTimeToWeekday(unixTime: currentUnixTime, timezone: "America/New_York", offset: 2)
```

should return "Wednesday" and so on.

Anything helps. Thanks.

Comment: The Unix time of `3920385` is February 15, 1970. Is that what you really want?

Comment: just typed a random number as an example

Comment: Given the new Unix time in your question, the results should be Tuesday and Wednesday, right?

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry I just quickly wrote the usage code with random stuff because unixTime is flexible and the specific one I put is not what I would use. Your answer did work though, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a DateFormatter. Use Calendar.

```
func unixTimeToWeekday(unixTime: Double, timeZone: String, offset: Int) -> String {
    if(timeZone == "" || unixTime == 0.0) {
        return ""
    } else {
        let time = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: unixTime)
        var cal = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        if let tz = TimeZone(identifier: timeZone) {
            cal.timeZone = tz
        }
        // Get the weekday for the given timezone.
        // Add the offset
        // Subtract 1 to convert from 1-7 to 0-6
        // Normalize to 0-6 using % 7
        let weekday = (cal.component(.weekday, from: time) + offset - 1) % 7

        // Get the weekday name for the user's locale
        return Calendar.current.weekdaySymbols[weekday]
    }
}

print(unixTimeToWeekday(unixTime: 1530676380, timeZone: "America/New_York", offset: 0))
print(unixTimeToWeekday(unixTime: 1530676380, timeZone: "America/New_York", offset: 1))
```

Output:

> Tuesday
>   Wednesday

since `1530676380` is 2018-07-03 23:53:00 EDT (Tuesday).